# MySQL JOIN empty table returns only one row

Tags: mysql, join

I have 3 tables: photos, users, votes.
I want to get all photos with usernames and votes:

```
SELECT
    `f`.`Photo`,
    `u`.`Name`,
            `u`.`Surname`,
    COUNT(`h`.`Id`) AS `Votes`
    FROM
        `photos` `f`
    JOIN
        `users` `u`
    ON
        `f`.`UserId` = `u`.`Id`
    LEFT JOIN
        `votes` `h`
    ON
        `f`.`Id` = `h`.`PhotoId`
    WHERE
        `f`.`Show` = '1'
    GROUP BY 
        `h`.`PhotoId`
```

Data:

```
photos:
---------------------------
|Id  | Photo     | UserId |
---------------------------
|1   | pic1.jpg  | 1      |
---------------------------
|2   | pic2.jpg  | 2      |
---------------------------
|3   | pic3.jpg  | 3      |
---------------------------

users:
---------------------------
|Id  | Name      | Surname|
---------------------------
|1   | User1     | Sur1   |
---------------------------
|2   | User2     | Sur2   |
---------------------------
|3   | User3     | Sur3   |
---------------------------

votes (is empty):
---------------------------
|Id  | PhotoId   | Date   |
---------------------------
```

The query above will return only **one row**, when there are no votes:

---

```
Photo     | Name   | Surname | Votes
-------------------------------------
pic1.jpg  | User1  | Sur1    | 0
-------------------------------------
```

but I'd like to get all three rows (for all three photos):

```
-------------------------------------
Photo     | Name   | Surname | Votes
-------------------------------------
pic1.jpg  | User1  | Sur1    | 0
-------------------------------------
pic2.jpg  | User2  | Sur2    | 0
-------------------------------------
pic3.jpg  | User3  | Sur3    | 0
-------------------------------------
```

SOLVED: The GROUP BY clause should be `f`.`Id`, not `h`.`PhotoId`:

```
SELECT
`f`.`Photo`,
`u`.`Name`,
        `u`.`Surname`,
COUNT(`h`.`Id`) AS `Votes`
FROM
    `photos` `f`
JOIN
    `users` `u`
ON
    `f`.`UserId` = `u`.`Id`
LEFT JOIN
    `votes` `h`
ON
    `f`.`Id` = `h`.`PhotoId`
WHERE
    `f`.`Show` = '1'
GROUP BY 
    `f`.`Id`
```

Comment: Is the `f.Show` in there significant?

Comment: To amplify on @Ray's comment, if `f.show` is `1` for only one photo row, then you'll get only one row back.

Comment: Thanks for response guys, but I've made a mistake in GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @Peter, you are expected to tag an answer as "Accepted" rather than editing the question title ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be grouping by `h.PhotoId`. If your votes table is empty, this column will be NULL all the way down. But when you LEFT JOIN on the votes table, it creates one row for each vote with duplicate details for all the rows in the non-votes tables. So you can group on any unique column from another table. `f.Id` is a good choice. So change your last line to:

```
GROUP BY
    `f`.`Id`
```